# Multiple versions of PHP through Nginx in Docker

Tags: php, docker, fastcgi

I run two docker containers for PHP5.6:

```
docker run --name php5 \
    -v /html1:/var/www/html/site1 \
    -d -p 9001:9000 php:5.6-fpm
```

And for PHP7:

```
docker run --name php7 \
  -v /html2:/var/www/html/site2 \
  -d -p 9000:9000 php:7-fpm
```

I run Docker container with Nginx:

```
docker run --name nginx-cache \
  -v /nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  -v /nginx/html1:/var/www/html/site1 \
  -v /nginx/html2:/var/www/html/site2 \
  -v /sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ \
  --link php5 --link php7 -d -p 9999:80 nginx
```

with `nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;
    gzip_disable      "msie6";


    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

with site1 config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        server_name site1;

        root /var/www/html/site1/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass  php5:9001;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        }
}
```

and site2 config:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name site2;

        root /var/www/html/site2/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass  php7:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        }
}
```

This request to site2 is 200 OK with proper response:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:9999/index.php \
  -H 'host: site2'
```

And for the request to site1:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:9999/index.php \
  -H 'host: site1'
```

In the Nginx container logs I always see:

> 2017/04/26 21:18:27 [error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection
>   refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server:
>   site1, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://172.17.0.3:9001", host: "site1"

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Ok I solved it, quite dummy mistake. For some reason I assumed that if I expose the port 9001 like this:

```
docker run --name php5 \
    -v /html1:/var/www/html/site1 \
    -d -p 9001:9000 php:5.6-fpm
```

then this port 9001 should be used in Nginx container which is connected to the other php5 container. This is wrong because the exposed network connection is different than linked one.

So the proper site1 config should be like this (the port is also 9000):

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        server_name site1;

        root /var/www/html/site1/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass  php5:9000; # <-- BOOOM!
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        }
}
```

Comment: so are you're saying no need to assign different ports for each PHP version, and just use the service name and default port as-is?