# Can I have NginX on a host and multiple versions of PHP in docker containers

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644963/multiple-versions-of-php-through-nginx-in-docker) but it didn't quite answer my question.

I've always installed my stack locally for development, NginX, PHP7, MySQL, and Couchbase. No Problems.

Now I have to work on a project that requires a lower version of PHP... And my team will have to work on it as well, so I've looked to Docker to try to find the solution.

In my existing NGINX conf files I send the requests off to php-fpm like this

```
   location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME $http_host;
    }
```

See the line

```
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
```

?

I was hoping to be able to create a docker container running a specific version of PHP and write it into the server block as above but with

```
fastcgi_pass   172.17.0.1:9000;
```

Where 172.17.0.1 is the IP of the container.

I have used, very simply,

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm
EXPOSE 9000
```

As my dockerfile. I can build an image, run the container, run bash in the container and see that PHP -I and PHP -v return what I expect.

Running docker inspect  has given me two IP addresses, 172.17.0.1, and 172.17.0.2 (I've tried both in the example above)

However, this set up is not working - when I try to visit the site in a browser I get an NGINX 504 gateway timeout error.

Guessing I'm missing something, but not sure what.

Happy to use docker compose if I need to, happy to mount volumes into the container if I need to. Just not sure what I need!:)

Comment: The `172` addresses are within Docker's network domain and should not be used like you're trying to use them. Docker handles networking to the host, so 127.0.0.1:9000 should apply only to the host.

Comment: If I were doing this I would include nginx in each container, unless there is some reason not to.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's best practices so I don't write that as a reply. What I tend to do is to expose only port 80 (and 443) on my server, and nginx is listening. Then I deploy multiple dockers with different languages / versions, and run them listening on their own specific port. It can be PHPApache, Ruby + Nginx etc etc... Then I use Nginx as a proxy to redirect specific request to specific port on my machine, which is fully handled by docker. Another thing I saw (not sure if good practice though...) is to use docker only, and add a VHOST argument.

Comment: Do not use the IP, use the container name (as the answer in the question you linked does).

Comment: @yivi I would have tried that if nginx was in a docker container

Comment: @Jay Blanchard i may try creating an nginx container, but i'm trying to avoid any interference with nginx and the apps that currently run natively on the host

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear to me from your answer. Then, do as Jay said earlier. Just connect to 127.0.0.1. No mistery there.

Comment: Logically, you'll have to stop you "local" php-fpm process, since they are both using the same port.

Comment: If you plan to put nginx in the containers just make sure they are configured to avoid nginx on the host, either through vhosts or ports. Typically I would shut down nginx on the host as I am not serving anything locally from the host other than the enabled Docker containers.